# Random Code Seed Producing Duplicates

Tags: java

I have the below test program which I'm attempting to use to seed a random number using phone number plus the current time.  It looks like the below is yielding duplicates.  Any ideas?

count=100000
size=683

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    static int LENGTH = 8;
    static String VAULES = "0123456789";
    static int cnt = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Long> codes = new HashSet<Long>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            Long seed = Long.valueOf(PHONE_VAULES) * 1000 + System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000L;

            codes.add(seed);
            System.out.println(generateRandomPassword(seed));
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("count="+ cnt);
        System.out.println("size="+ codes.size());
    }

    public static String generateRandomPassword(long seed) {
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        random.setSeed(seed);
        return Long.toString(random.nextLong()).substring(1, CODE_LENGTH + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not reset the seed like that. You're using `SecureRandom`, don't set the seed at all. Why are you setting the **seed**? What does *using phone number plus the current time* mean?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I want to produce a random number based on a phone number of a user and a timestamp to ensure that its a random number but unique to them.

Comment: [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) means that isn't guaranteed. Either use a sequential number generator (1,2,3) or plan for duplicates (regardless, don't seed a `SecureRandom` - it's self seeding). And never update the `seed` on every call to `random`; you're virtually guaranteed to not get a random result.

Comment: Why are you using a seed at all if you don't want duplicates?

Comment: think of it as a temp password, it would be easily hackable if I provided some sequence number.

Comment: It does not make sense to use a different random generator for each number. Don't do that.

Comment: Okay. Then generate the password and store it, a `SecureRandom` already includes a time component internally and your seeding attempts are interfering with its' internal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's yeilding duplicates because you're using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which means that for one millisecond, this value doesn't change, and so does your seed. And you go through your loop multiple times during one millisecond

I don't think there is a  way to get time in nanosecond. You should wait at least one milliseconds (if it's possible for your application)

Answer (score -1):

The number of different seed you produce is directly linked to the number of milliseconds taken to generate all your seeds. Measuring the time your loop takes using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then printing it, I always had `time = size-1`.

Solution : use `System.nanoTime()` instead.

Doing this change, you'll consistently have `size=1000`. This is because of the `%1000L`, which maxes the number of possible outputs to 1000 for any given phone number. Remove it if you can.

EDIT : from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html :

> public void setSeed(long seed)
>
> Reseeds this random object, using the eight bytes contained in the given long seed. The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.

While what the OP is doing might not be necessary, it shouldn't be a security risk, since `setSeed` doesn't reset the `SecureRandom` object into a predictable state.

Also, producing the same seed over and over isn't really a problem because of the same fact : in the end, the security relies on `SecureRandom`'s internal works, not on the seed generation ...